# Mysql data type to make null value '0', and nonnull value '1'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table like:

column:

```
Emails, Country, Inactive
```

I want to import list "csv" to the table and I want to make it so that if a row contains data in the "inactive" column the value will be set to "1" and if its empty "0". 
the column "inactive" in my list contains all sorts of string and some are null.
it doesn't matter what data it has it just important that after its imported to the table I’d get to know if its containing data or not assuming that if its not than the email is active.

Comment: is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the values 0 or 1 based on inactive field:

```
select emails, country, if(inactive is null or inactive = '', 0, 1) as inactive
from mytable
```

If we want to insert the data into another table then, we need to wrap this query into insert statement as shown below:

```
insert into newtable(emails, country, inactive)
select emails, country, if(inactive is null or inactive = '', 0, 1) as inactive
from mytable
```

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/864b7c/2/0).

Comment: but i want it to set the fileds that way not just present them like that

Comment: I have added that bit in my answer.

Comment: and last one, can you give me one like this for a table where inactive is 'sometext' and to convert to 1/0?

Comment: Here you go:
`insert into newtable(emails, country, inactive)
select emails, country, if(inactive = 'sometext', 0, 1) as inactive
from mytable`